# Why does HTTP service require @Injectable decorator and a custom service does not in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Why is it that I need to include `@Injectable` when doing DI using `http`, but I don't need it when doing DI using a custom service I created?

**For example:**

```
//no @Injectable() here
export class Test {
 constructor(private customService: CustomService){}
}

/*-------------*/

@Injectable() // <== required here
export class HttpTest {
 constructor(private http: Http){}
}
```

Comment: Is it working? Please create plunker. It doesn't work for me. `Can't resolve all parameters for Test: (?)` https://plnkr.co/edit/UzwdQ0OUYStCoJcWzija?p=preview

Comment: Please, show how Test is used. The statement is not true, it will surely throw injector error when being used as a service.

Answer (score 1):

`@Injectable()` is needed if you have a parameter in constructor that needs to be injected. See [Why `@Injectable()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#why-_-injectable-_-)

> `@Injectable()` marks a class as available to an injector for
>   instantiation. Generally speaking, an injector reports an error when
>   trying to instantiate a class that is not marked as `@Injectable()`.
>
> As it happens, you could have omitted `@Injectable()` from the first
>   version of `HeroService` because it had no injected parameters. But you
>   must have it now that the service has an injected dependency. You need
>   it because Angular requires constructor parameter metadata in order to
>   inject a `Logger`.

---

Your example doesn't work because it requires `@Injectable()` on the `Test` class